# Unable to use docker for windows after uninstalling toolbox

Tags: docker

I upgraded to Win 10 Pro today and decided to switch over to Docker for Windows. I uninstalled toolbox first and then installed Docker for Windows, but now when I run any docker commands, it tries to look for Virtualbox/docker toolbox stuff, but that doesn't exist anymore/won't work.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: take a look at your system variables there might still be something left that points docker to ttoolbox specifically :"DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH"

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't that sysvar specifically, but I uninstalled Docker for Windows, removed all references to Docker in the sysvars, and then reinstalled. `hello-world` runs at least!